Can you use the same hand for a Fist and a Weapon attack with a Free-hand weapon?
Spirit Warrior Dedication gives you Overwhelming Combination:

Requirements
You’re wielding a one-handed melee weapon or a melee weapon with the agile or finesse trait;
Effects Make two Strikes against a target within your reach, one with the required weapon and one with your fist unarmed attack. If both hit the same target, combine their damage for the purposes of its resistances and weaknesses. Apply your multiple attack penalty to each Strike normally.

Can I do both the weapon and fist attacks with the same hand? (I might be a Thaumaturge, or have a shield in the other hand).
With a Free-hand weapon:

When you’re not wielding anything and not otherwise using the hand, you can use abilities that require you to have a hand free as well as those that require you to be wielding a weapon in that hand. Each of your hands can have only one free-hand weapon on it.

A fist attack requires you have a hand free, which is allowed by the Free-hand trait.

Probably Not

A fist attack requires you have a hand free, which is allowed by the Free-hand trait.

More specifically, this limitation seems to come from the unarmed trait describing that a fist is generally treated as a free-hand weapon:

Unarmed: An unarmed attack uses your body rather than a manufactured weapon. An unarmed attack isn’t a weapon, though has a weapon group and might have weapon traits. An unarmed attack can’t be Disarmed. It also doesn’t take up a hand, though a fist or other grasping appendage generally works like a free-hand weapon.

So the requirements here are effectively duplicated, that:

Striking with your free-hand weapon requires that you’re not wielding anything and not otherwise using the hand
Striking with your fist requires that you’re not wielding anything and not otherwise using the hand

Abilities like Climb which require a free hand can still be used while wielding a free-hand weapon, but the requirements for making a fist Strike are more specific than just having a free hand.
It's also a bit of a narrative stretch to allow a fist Strike through a free-hand weapon like a gauntlet. Even if the free-handedness is interpreted to cover the fist Strike requirements, it might make sense to ignore that as a specific exception to "generally works like a free-hand weapon" in pursuit of verisimilitude.
